# 8 bit versus 32 bit bias with exponet

Tags: c, binary, bit

I am trying to work my way thru binary numbers and normalized values.  I am confused because we were taught that numbers are represented as 8 bit values.  We would do examples with 8 bits where 1 bit was the sign, the next 4 bits were the exponent and then the last 3 were for the number.  It was going ok then we jump into 32 bit numbers where the 1 bit is the sign the next 8 are the exponent and the final 23 are the remaining number.

My question is why the different representations? Sometimes numbers are 8 bits sometimes 32 bits? why not make them 3 bits then sometimes 13 bits? Or make them 40 bits and 64 bits? There appears to be no rhyme or reason.  Are we dealing with 8 bits when we talk about numbers or 32? Here is an example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi5RXPBO-8E

Any help explaining would help.  Right now I don't know if I should study the material based on 8 bits or 32 bits with the 1st bit a sign, second 8 the exponent and last 23 the actual number.  Very confused.

Comment: representable range. there's only so many numbers you can squeeze into 8 bits, v.s. what you can squeeze into 32bit. e.g. just pulling numbers out of a hat, maybe your 8bit representation could do  `-15.999 -> +16.000`, while the 32bit version could do `-15,999,999.999 999 999 -> +16,000,000,000.000 000 000`

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the number of bits. In both the 8- and 32-bit cases, you describe a format that uses _x_ exponent bits and _y_ mantissa bits. The logic behind the format is the same regardless of what the values of _x_ and _y_ happen to be.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were taught how floating point numbers were represented using 8-bits as it's much easier to do the math with smaller numbers; however, you can only represent so many numbers with 8-bits (256 different numbers to be exact).

As you said you learned how floating point numbers work with 8 bits.

SEEEENNN  -- Where s is the sign bit, E is the exponent and N is the number/ significand bits

the sign of the number is simply -1 to the sign bit

the exponent is the eponent bets represented as a signed integer or as an unsigned integer minus the representations bias

the significand is 1 + SUM i = 1 to p N[i]*2^(-i) where p is the precision of the number/ number of bits for the significand

the value can be computed as:
-1^S * 2^(exponent) * significand

As a more concrete example (exponent bias of 2^(4-1)-1 = 7)

0 1000 101

```
s = 0
exponent = 8 - 7 = 1
significand = 1 + 0.5 * 1 + 0.25 * 0 + 0.125 * 1 = 1.625
value = (-1)^0 + 1.625 * 2^1 = 3.25
```

The same representation scheme can be applied to any number of bits. In that regard it is fairly arbitrary to chose the value 8 or 32.

32 and 64 bits are often chosen to represent floating point numbers in binary format because they are powers of 2, are easily stored in memory (integer number of bytes) and computer ALU's are designed to work with 32/64 bit numbers.

In C a float is 32 bits and a double is 64 bits.

You can read more on IEEE-754 floating point representation. Wikipedia has a good explanation of how it works [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)